# getting error while executing small shell script program

Tags: shell

(SHELL SCRIPT)

I'm getting this "`error :2a.sh: 7: [: missing ]`"
while I want answer for sum of even numbers until *n*<sup>th</sup> number

```
echo "enter a number :"  
read n  
s=0  
i=0  
while [ $i -le $n ]  
do  
if [ $(expr $i % 2)  -eq 0]  
then  
s=$(expr $i + 1)  
fi  
i=$(expr $i + 1)  
done  
echo " ans :"  
echo $s
```

output I'm getting:

```
enter a number :  
10  
2a.sh: 7: [: missing ]  
ans:  
0
```

Comment: Add a space before the ']'. Bash workson tokens, will not break '0]' to separate tokens.

Comment: `0]` - there is a missing space